# How to render characters instead of hex? (\x60)

Tags: awk, text, encoding, utf-8

I have a file *(file.txt)* with this content:

file.txt:

```
+   "Chapter 8\n“So Much More Than Just an ‘A’”: A Transformative High School and University Writing Center Partnership

+   "Chapter 9\n“Oh, I Get By with a Little Help from My Friends”: Short-Term Writing Center/Community Collaborations"
```

My code extracts certain data from this with gawk, and then writes the results to a new file *(nav.txt)* using **printf**.

nav.txt:

```
Chapter 8  \xE2\x80\x9CSo Much More Than Just an \xE2\x80\x98A\xE2\x80\x99\xE2\x80\x9D: A Transformative High School and University Writing Center Partnership

Chapter 9 \xE2\x80\x9COh, I Get By with a Little Help from My Friends\xE2\x80\x9D: Short-Term
```

Does anyone know why the special characters (like ‘, -, etc) render as these weird hex codes? (\xE2\x80\x98A, \xE2\x80\x9D, etc)

If so, how can I output the correct characters to *nav.txt*, instead of their hex equivelants?

my gawk code, running on Ubuntu:

```
gawk '
    match($0, /^[\|\+-].*"([^"]+)".*#([[:digit:]]+)/, m) {
        printf "<li>\n     <a href=\"mybook%04d.xhtml\">%s</a>\n    </li>\n", m[2], m[1] >> "nav.txt"
    }
' file.txt
```

Comment: Please include your `printf` statement and ideally the rest of the minimally required code to reproduce this. I tried in gawk 4.2.1 and a `printf "%c "...` worked correctly.

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `print( '\xE2\x80\x9CSo Much More Than Just an \xE2\x80\x98A\xE2\x80\x99\xE2\x80\x9D'.encode( 'latin1').decode('utf-8'))` shows `“So Much More Than Just an ‘A’”`.

Comment: Running the awk script you provided on the sample input you provided produces no output. Please [edit] your question to provide a working [mcve] **that just demonstrates the problem you want help with**, not whatever code you have lying around that you first noticed had the problem, so we can help you. And don't create a [mcve] that writes it's output to some other file instead of just stdout as that's needlessly cumbersome for demonstrating your problem.